# Automatically set length of vertical bars with \left and \right

Tags: formatting, vertical

If I write

```
\[\left||x|-|y|\right|\]
```

I would expect it to look like the second of the following two expressions:

[image]

which I got by writing

```
\[\Big||x|-|y|\Big|\]
```

Shouldn't `\left` and `\right` adjust the size automatically? Or do I have to write `\Big` whenever I have two vertical bars, one after the other?

Comment: This question has already been asked many times; [Why aren't the `\left` and `\right` before my parentheses changing their size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40607) and [Parentheses with automatically increasing heights](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/364412) have answers that provide a viable, yet questionable, solution that works autoatically.

Answer (score 6):

You should use  `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command from mathtools to  define an `\abs`  command. Doing so, you obtain  a `\abs*` version which adds an implicit `\left \right` pair and detects the inner `\abs`. For fine-tuning you also have four variants with an optional argument: `\abs[\big]`, `\abs[\Big]`, &c.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \abs{\abs{x}-\abs{y}} & \le \abs{x-y} \\
    \abs*{\abs{x}-\abs{y}} & \le \abs{x-y}\\
    \abs[\Big]{\abs{x}-\abs{y}} & \le \abs{x-y}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

@Mico made me observe the starred version works as you want because of the `fourier` font which uses special values of the parameters which control the delimiters sizes: `\delimitershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor`. It suffices to add \delimitershortfall=-1sp`to obtain`the same result with the default `Computer Modern`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \abs{\abs{x}-\abs{y}} & \le \abs{x-y} \\
    \abs*{\abs{x}-\abs{y}} & \le \abs{x-y}\\
\end{align*}
\delimitershortfall=-1sp
\begin{align*}
    \abs{\abs{x}-\abs{y}} & \le \abs{x-y} \\
    \abs*{\abs{x}-\abs{y}} & \le \abs{x-y}\\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to mention that if the OP doesn't wish to use the `fourier` font package, a similar effect (i.e., automatic growth of matched delimiters) may be achieved by executing `\setlength{\delimitershortfall}{-1sp}`.

Comment: @Mico: I didn't even know it was using the fourier fonts which made the starred version work. I used them only because I started with an already existing short file and changed a couple of lines. I'll update my answer in a moment, of course.

Answer (score 2):

`\left` and `\right` adjust size automatically, but in a purely typographic way, not semantic. Typographically, the inner `|` does not  incur the need for bigger `|` than `x` already did.

So yes, you need to fine tune this if you want to emphasize the outer `|`. The same goes for parentheses.